# scripts not enqueueing

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have been beating my head against this for a couple of hours now and can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to enqueue a script into my page with the following code in my functions.php.

```
function my_slider_scripts() {
$scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js';
wp_register_script( 'nivo-slider-pack', $scriptsrc );

    wp_enqueue_script('nivo-slider-pack');
} 

add_action( 'wp-enqueue_scripts', 'my_slider_scripts' );
```

I have looked at the codex and every tutorial I can find and nothing seems to make this work. I should mention I am using a child theme. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

try `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_slider_scripts')`

the hook doesn't have a dash. It's an underscore.

Comment: i fixed the typo and the scripts are still not being included in the page. Is there something that needs to be added to the page template file?

Comment: You have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` calls in your header and footer templates, right?

Comment: yes! To be honest I moved onto another solution for this. It was taking to much time. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

(i deleted my old answer in favour of this)

1. Check the Location ... is the Nivo Slider in your theme / stylesheet folder or in the plugins directory?

You're currently using
`$scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js';`

maybe it should be

```
function my_scripts_method() {  
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', plugins_url('/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is some information for you so that you understand how things work with wp_enqueue_scripts.

You need to know the priority order for the wp_enqueue_scripts. Please check the below order of the hooks can be run........

1. muplugins_loaded
2. registered_taxonomy
3. registered_post_type
4. plugins_loaded
5. sanitize_comment_cookies
6. setup_theme
7. load_textdomain
8. after_setup_theme
9. auth_cookie_malformed
10. auth_cookie_valid
11. set_current_user
12. **init**
13. widgets_init
14. register_sidebar
15. wp_register_sidebar_widget
16. wp_default_scripts
17. wp_default_stypes
18. admin_bar_init
19. add_admin_bar_menus
20. wp_loaded
21. parse_request
22. send_headers
23. parse_query
24. pre_get_posts
25. posts_selection
26. wp
27. template_redirect
28. get_header
29. wp_head
30. **wp_enqueue_scripts**
31. wp_print_styles
32. wp_print_scripts

... and so one.....

So you see you can add it in the `init` hook and doing so it will be called as high priority than below the listing.

If you found your files are not loading and you surely can use a high priority hook.

If you found your wp_enqueue_script is not being called, you can use this simple trick to get it work for your theme or plugin.

```
    <?php

    function my_slider_scripts() {
$scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js';
wp_register_script( 'nivo-slider-pack', $scriptsrc );

    wp_enqueue_script('nivo-slider-pack');
} 

        add_action( 'init', 'my_slider_scripts' );



    ?>
```

Comment: `init` should *not* be used to enqueue scripts, always use `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: In my answer I show you why and in which situation you should use init hook.

Comment: In your answer you give no compelling reason why you should use the wrong hook, and how it would possibly fix the issue.